# Battlefield 4 Single player conquest

Tags: battlefield-4

Does Battlefield 4 have single player conquest mode, like in Battlefield 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look a around and unfortunately it appears that battlefield does not include a single player system for multiplayer game types.

Many have asked for the inclusion of modes like 'single player conquest' but it appears that dice/ea have not included this feature.